# Is there a way to put double quotes around selected text?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, phpstorm

I used to use Sublime Text 2 but now I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 and PhpStorm. In these I can not insert double quotes in a selected text like I can do in Sublime Text.

In Sublime Text when you select some text and then press double quotes (`Shift + 2`) the text does not disappear but double quotes get inserted around selected text.

Is there a way to do that in VS2015 and PhpStorm?

Comment: PhpStorm: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Insert pair quote` -- how it works may depend on context & language used.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne the option to enable that feature were in the same page it was: "Surround selection on typeing quote or brace" instead "Insert pair quote".